# Bug with hint in outlined TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml

I faced with an annoying bug: hint in focused state overlaps stroke (border of textInputLayout) when I set corner radius more than 8dp. I tried to set padding for editTextView, but it doesn't helped me. Are there any solutions?

**Bug:**

[image]

**Layout:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/global_search_ti_container"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_search_24dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/global_search_ti_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:hint="@string/search_by_people"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/soft_white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/soft_red"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Styles:**

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle"
        parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="android:layout_margin">16dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">30dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">30dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">30dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">30dp</item>
        <item name="startIconTint">@color/soft_red</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_stroke_color</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">1.5dp</item>
        <item name="errorEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_input_hint</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/soft_red</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this issue: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2145

[image: screenshot]

According to [this commit](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/79ae9b1351159533b58939b9f11c72fc779eede1) the problem should have been solved in 1.5.0-alpha05. Please check how it works on the specified version of the library

Comment: Yeah, it solved my problem. Quite annoying presence of bugs in released versions..